# Finding and removing specific element from array based on multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am trying to remove specific elements from an array based on data I'm getting from an API. The API returns an array of objects like this `{"videoDate":"07/31/2020","videoTime":"1:00 AM"}`. I have an existing array with items that look like this `"07/31/2020 1:00 AM"`. My intention is to check if the existing array contains an item with a string matching both the `videoDate` and `videoTime` strings from the object and remove them.

```js
        let responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
        responseArray.forEach((item) => {
          dayArray.forEach((day) =>  {
            if (day.includes(item.videoDate) && day.includes(item.videoTime)) {
              let index = dayArray.findIndex(item => item.videoDate && item.videoTime);
              dayArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
          });
        });
        console.log(dayArray);
```

The above code flags everything and returns an empty `dayArray`.

```js
        let responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
        responseArray.forEach((item) => {
          dayArray.forEach((day) =>  {
            if (day.includes(item.videoDate) && day.includes(item.videoTime)) {
              // ts-ignore
              let index = dayArray.findIndex(item.videoDate && item.videoTime);
              dayArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
          });
        });
       console.log(dayArray);
```

The above code throws an error `TypeError: 1:00 AM is not a function`

```js
        response.forEach((item) => {
          dayArray.forEach((day) =>  {
            if (day.includes(item.videoDate) && day.includes(item.videoTime)) {
              // ts-ignore
              let index = dayArray.findIndex(item.videoDate && item.videoTime);
              dayArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
          });
        });
        console.log(dayArray);
```

The above code where I'm not parsing the response first returns `response.forEach is not a function`

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I edited my previous solution, I believed, what you wanted to do is if the items (date and time) in the array matches any value in the returned object, remove the item from the array.

Test it and give feed back

```
let response = `[{"videoDate":"07/31/2020","videoTime":"1:00 AM"}]`
 let dayArray = ["07/31/2020 1:00 AM"];
  let responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
  dayArray.forEach((el, i) => {    
      let item = el.split(/(^[^\s]*)\s/);
      item.shift();
       responseArray.forEach((obj) => {
            let obj_vals = Object.values(obj);
            if(obj_vals.indexOf(item[0]) != -1 && obj_vals.indexOf(item[1]) != -1 ) dayArray.splice(i, 1);
        }); });
        
        console.log(dayArray)
```

Comment: Try to show properly how your array of object and array of values are stored.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. This is compiling but not properly filtering out the matching value.

Comment: forgot to tag you

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.